# Remote push notifications on Android with RAD Studio XE6 using my own server

Tags: android, delphi, push-notification

I need to develop an application on Android that receives messages from my server in push mode,
 even when the app is closed. 
That is, suppose we have 100 apps installed, these apps should receive a text message from my server. 
If the application on Android is closed, you should receive a notification, then tap the notification, the application should open showing the entire message.

I have no experience on the BAAS services, so would appreciate a small example "client / server"

Comment: For Kinvey (which uses Google Cloud Messaging), an overview can be found here: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/push#

Comment: I have seen examples of push services as Kinvey, but I want to use my server and also develop the "server" side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive the push messages without Google Cloud Messaging, you need a client app which is constantly running, or which is launched in regular intervals (by the Android AlarmManager).

You can use any technology / protocol you like, for example HTTP(S), [MQTT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT) or STOMP to implement the client/server communication.

With HTTP(S) you can use long polling or upgrade to WebSocket connections.

A major disadvantage is that these solutions will consume more resources (CPU, battery) compared with the built-in Google Cloud Messaging.